# Sending email from website using mailto link

Tags: outlook, spam, mailto, quoted-printable

That might be silly question but I really need to know the answer. If I got the Outlook client installed on my machine and I click on the mailto link on the website the subject and body specified in the link is passed to the client. Is anything else attached to the message? Any headers or addition information about my website?

I am asking this question because I have such a link on my website and every time I test it the email fails spam checks with Postini.

I also get this message:

- Your email has been encoded as 'Quoted-printable', and yet one of the lines of content is longer than the maximum 76 characters. No line within a quoted-printable body may exceed that size.

When I remove long links I am not getting this message but the email still fails the Postinig check.

Thanks for help,
Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mailto:` links are just interpreted by the browser as a signal to say "Open the default mail client to send an email to this person". Everything else is treated as a classic mail by Outlook.

Maybe it is something in your mail that Postini recognises as a potential spam phrase?

Comment: Thanks. the body of the message has title of the article, short introduction and few links. I sent the same email from my personal GMAIL account (the same title and body) and this time it succeeded with Postini. For me it looks like the problem is with my company SMTP settings?

Comment: Some SMTP servers block mails coming from unknown SMTP server. If your company SMTP server isn't recognized by the SMTP relay as a trusted mail server, your mail can be marked as spam.